# How to use jobs to manage task by script produce

Tags: shell-script

If I have a `run_script`, and it's content is:

```
#run_script file
ls
```

Then I can use `bash run_script` to run the `ls` command. But now I have a `run_script`, and it's content is:

```
#run_script file
python3 mate30pro5g.py & python3 Mathematica.py & python3 opencv.py &
```

I find I cannot check any background task by command `jobs` after I have run `bash run_script`. But I can find all task is running by `ps aux | grep python3`. But I want to use `jobs` to manage all task, why this command cannot find check it? What I have missed?

Comment: does the script work from command line without error?

Comment: @jsotola Sorry I know all tasks have built, just `jobs` cannot find it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lose job control if you start a new shell with `bash run_script`. 
Your python processes are run as children of the newly started bash process and when your script terminates they are detached from its (now dead) parent process.
To start the programs as children of your current shell, you can source your script with

```
. run_script
```

You can see the difference with `ps auxf`.